# Playa link with matrix field is not working

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, playa, channel

I am using playa with in matrix field type and want to get the url of playa link.

For eg:-

I have created Channel (named as XYZ) and following fields  as below :

```
a) gallery_name : text

b) gallery : matrix

   i) link  : Playa
   ii) link_text : text
```

Now i want to show gallery link and link_text.

I am using code below :

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="xyz"}

    {gallery_name} <br/>

    {gallery}       
        <a href="{link}{page_uri}{/link}">{link_text}</a> 
    {/gallery}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the code `<a href="{link}{page_uri}{/link}">` is not working.

```
{link}{page_uri}{/link}
```

this code is not showing playa link that is selected before for respective text.

So what is missing/wrong here. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making work playa link:

1) Double check you have selected a published entry.
OR
2) Open your playa field to edit (from Admin->Channel->Channel fields->select gallery to edit) and recheck settings and save field.

Comment: Please check publish setting.